# Parallel BLAST program takes too long

Tags: python, parallel-processing, bioinformatics, biopython, blast

When I run the following code I do not even get one blast result. Could someone let me know if they spot a bug?

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time


def blast_sequences_parallel(seq_record):
    result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", seq_record.seq, entrez_query='txid10239[viruses]')
    blast_records = NCBIXML.parse(result_handle)
    return blast_records


if __name__ == "__main__":
    file = "file.fa"
    get_number_of_seqs(file)
    seq_records = SeqIO.parse(file, "fasta")
    t1 = time.time()
    p = Pool()
    results = p.map(blast_sequences_parallel, seq_records)
    p.close()
    p.join()

    print("Pool took:", time.time() - t1)
    print(results)
```

I have 73,000 sequences to run so I was trying to make it faster. I am running it on a super computer. Any suggestions for how much memory I would need and how many cores/nodes? I also have tried the following command in shell:

```
blastn -query file.fa -remote
```

But I get an error message suggesting that I need to download a database? Is there a way to use the online server for the search? If there is a way, can I search only against virus genomes?

Answer (score 0):

With 73K sequences you should download an appropriate db and run BLAST locally rather than attempting to run it online. Biopython also has a wrapper for this `from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbiblastxCommandline` but it can be even easier just to run BLAST from the command line. See also the relevant biopython [docs](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec121).

NCBI provide a set of dbs pre-made (or you can build your own from a FASTA file via `makeblastdb`): https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/